# Remove duplicates from my academic transcript

Tags: code-golf, string, array

Consider a list of subject, grade pairs. E.g.

```
[("Latin", "A"),  ("French", "A*"),  ("Math", "B"), ("Latin", "A*")]
```

The task is to return the same list but with each subject given at most once. Where a subject occurred more than once originally, the returned list should have the highest grade for that subject.

Using the UK system, "A*" is a better grade than "A" and of course "A" is better than "B" etc. Only "A" can be followed by an asterisk.

The output for this case should be:

```
[("Latin", "A*"),  ("French", "A*"),  ("Math", "B")]
```

Another example:

```
[("Latin", "A*"),  ("French", "A*"),  ("Math", "B"), ("French", "A*"), ("Math", "C")]
```

The output should be:

```
[("Latin", "A*"),  ("French", "A*"),  ("Math", "B")]
```

Your returned output list can be in any order you like.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Languages I am hoping for:

- Python, because I wrote a terrible solution in python which inspired this question. **Done**.
- C. Because real men/women code in C when it makes no sense for the problem at hand. **Done**.
- Julia. Because it's an awesome language.

## Input assumptions

You can assume there are no more than 10 subject/grade pairs, the input is printable ASCII and there are no spaces within the subject names.

Comment: Can we take multiset as input or output set?

Comment: Is A* the only grade which is not a single letter graded according to its place in the alphabet?

Comment: @l4m2 yes to both

Comment: @UnrelatedString I just answered that in the question. The answer is yes.

Comment: Suggest some cases where multiple same score exist

Comment: If you're going to use the UK grade system, please also use the UK subject name - it's called "maths" here.

Comment: just curious, what was your python solution?

Comment: Could you describe more about how "UK system" works? For I can understand it has `A*`, `A`, `B`, and, `C` from your post. Will it have more levels?

Comment: @tsh I understand it can go down to E and then below that there is a U. So the full list is  A*, A, B, C, D, E, U.

Comment: @Neil What should I do if I write a challenge about an Arabic counting system?

Comment: ‮Write it right to left perhaps?‬

Comment: Can we output the pairs in reverse order, with the grade first?

Comment: @Shaggy sorry, no

Comment: What assumptions can we make about what characters are or aren't present in the subject names? (Are they always printable ASCII? Can they contain spaces? Etc.)

Comment: Also, is there a maximum number of subject/grade pairs we have to handle? I'm asking because I'm thinking of using a fixed-size array in C.

Comment: @DLosc All printable ASCII and let's set the max number of subject/grade pairs to 10.

Answer (score 8):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
⁽hġ‡tṘv∵
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigb1oxKHigKF04bmYduKItSIsIiIsIlsoXCJMYXRpblwiLCBcIkFcIiksICAoXCJGcmVuY2hcIiwgXCJBKlwiKSwgIChcIk1hdGhcIiwgXCJCXCIpLCAoXCJMYXRpblwiLCBcIkEqXCIpXSJd)

Sort by the reverse of each grade, group by subject, best of each subject group

*-1 thanks to emanresuA*

### Explained

```
⁽hġ‡tṘv∵
⁽hġ       # Group subjects by their subject
      v∵  # Get the maximum of each group by
   ‡tṘ    # Reversed grade.
```

Comment: How did you resolve the order of A*?

Comment: By reversing each grade. `*A` comes before `A` lexographically in python, meaning it also comes before in Vyxal.

Comment: [8](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigb1oxKHigKF04bmYduKItSIsIiIsIlsoXCJMYXRpblwiLCBcIkFcIiksICAoXCJGcmVuY2hcIiwgXCJBKlwiKSwgIChcIk1hdGhcIiwgXCJCXCIpLCAoXCJMYXRpblwiLCBcIkEqXCIpXSJd)

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 58 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
s=nubBy((.fst).(==).fst).sortOn(last.snd)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zco9DsIwDIbhnVNEFoODqtwgAwUxteoBEIOBolqkbhWbgdOHvwEhtu979Qyk1z6lUnicp2xuS0ahYbWFRrkd6ztiuKj5gDH6z9Kn6wQTqQWVsy8jscQ5s9hS9wgNGQtUDtYr8JVzCLvcy2n4SS3ZO9Sv/y@@YAP@UB4)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
(c?f)a=c(f a).f
s=nubBy((==)?fst).sortBy(compare?(last.snd))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZctBCsIwEIXhfU8RgosZKblBKFZxVU8gLsaY0GCalsy48PSxuhFx@T7@NxLffUq1xmmZi6gDCZkhsjTguoBkHQRFaELDNj@u/RPAWuwCCxpeDyu4eVqo@A4SsRjON8Q6Ucx2KTHLhs@gB5KYdav0bquxVQr0sfjsxh86kXygf@//4hvsNV7qCw)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 84 bytes

```hs
import Data.List;import Data.Function
s=nubBy(on(==)fst).sortBy(on compare$last.snd)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcoxDsIgFIDh3VMQ0gFMwwUMg9V0ak9gHJ6IKZE@CO918PSoXdQ4/l/@CejuY6w1zDkVFkdgMEMg3n1Dv6DjkHBDFpdL91AJlbX6RqwNva5VhEtzhuKbCMSG8KrrDAFtLgG5oZOSA3BA2Qq530rdCqFkXzy66YdG4BW6d/8fn@Eg9bk@AQ)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 97 bytes

```hs
import Data.List;import Data.Function
g"A*"="@";g s=s
s=nubBy(on(==)fst).sortBy(on compare$g.snd)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBDoIwEAXQPadoJixaQ7gAaaJIWOEJjIsRERphSjrDwtNXYaPG5X/5/w/Ij24cY3TT7IOoCgXzxrEU31Av1IrzlPRw2IGFPRS9YssJW1qu5VN70taaO4vJ@b3aRLV@mjF0aZ8z3Uyc0JGdgyNJ@ayhQXEEmVofTaaUhjp01A4/dELZoFzzf@NTOIK5xBc)

Comment: [Define `on` yourself for 78](https://tio.run/##ZYtNCsIwEEb3PUVIu8hIyQ2ysIqregJxMdbYBpsfMiPo6WPrRsTNB@/xvgnpbue5FOdTzCz2yKh7R1xFVcMonkYtU4MeKzLhceleKipj4EYMmpbHKsQQfcJsmxmJNYUrFI8umJRd4IZOSvbILshWyO1GQiuEkodswzD9qCPyR3Qr/xffYCfhXN4)

Comment: 61: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpBCsIwEIXhfU8xDC4SKblBKFbpquIBxMVEKw2mY8mMC08ftRsRV4/3840ktyGlUuI037PCjpRcH0UraoK/igL5ZUIlnh@hfZrGOnnTA5tEok74YstEkf2cI@tKjgZ70shYA27WaGsAg10e@Dz@pD3pEtrP/xdfsEV7Ki8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: i wouldnot mind having `on` and `sortOn` and `nubOn` in `Prelude.hs` to undercut 30.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 52 bytes

```python
lambda x:dict(sorted(x,key=lambda n:n[1][~0])[::-1])
```

is there a way to golf the list reversal?

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXISc5NSEhUqrFIyk0s0ivOLSlJTNCp0slMrbaFSeVZ50Yax0XUGsZrRVla6hrGaUL1xBUWZeSUaaRrRGko-iSWZeUo6CkqOWkqaOgoKGkpuRal5yRkoQr6JJWABJxAfWYUzRAAmD-TGakJtWbAAQgMA)

Comment: Is ~0 the same as -1?

Comment: indeed, even though it doesn't shorten the code, it's an amusing property (`~n` is `-n-1`)

Comment: [You can sidestep the reversal altogether, but it's no shorter.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3TXISc5NSEhUqrFIyk0s0ivOLSlJTNCp0slMrbaFSeVa6-UUpGnnRhrHRdQaxmpqaUL1xBUWZeSUaaRrRGko-iSWZeUo6CkqOWkqaOgoKGkpuRal5yRkoQr6JJWABJxAfWYUzRAAmD-TGwmxZsABCAwA)

Comment: 51 in python 2: `lambda x:dict(sorted(x,key=lambda n:\`n\`[-3])[::-1])`

Comment: @tsh could you explain what this shorter version is doing please

Comment: @Simd `\`x\`` in python 2 is similar to `str(x)` in python 3. It actually do the same thing as your currently one.

Answer (score 7):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org), 82 bytes

```haskell
import Dict
List.sortBy(Tuple.second>>String.reverse)>>List.reverse>>Dict.fromList
```

Takes a list and returns a dict.

[`>>`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/1.0.5/Basics#(%3E%3E)) is function composition in the reversed direction: `f>>g` in Elm is `g.f` in Haskell.

According to [the source code of Elm's core package](https://github.com/elm/core/blob/65cea00afa0de03d7dda0487d964a305fc3d58e3/src/Dict.elm#L607-L610), `Dict.fromList` will keep the last value when there are duplicate keys.

You can try it [here](https://elm-lang.org/try). Here is a full test program:

```haskell
import Html exposing (text)

import Dict
f=List.sortBy(Tuple.second>>String.reverse)>>List.reverse>>Dict.fromList

main = 
  [("Latin", "A*"),  ("French", "B"),  ("Math", "A"), ("French", "A*"), ("Math", "C")]
  |> f
  |> Debug.toString
  |> text
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> <s>9</s> <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
ZḢ«/ƙ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q4Y5Fh1brH5v5/3C7u2bWo8Z9XFz//0drKPkklmTmKekoKDkqaeooKGgouRWl5iVngEW0oEK@iSVgAScQH1kLUEGsjgKFpjhhGqJFtCnoKhAKnIHGAgA)

```
    ƙ    Group pairs by
ZḢ       their first elements,
    ƙ    and for each group
   /     reduce by
  «      recursively vectorizing minimum.
```

The vectorizing minimum leaves the shared subject name unchanged while taking the minimum of the letter grades, and the vectorization mechanism's length mismatch handling adds an asterisk if any of the grades for that subject has an asterisk.

Comment: The TIO output seems to contain multiple copies of the same subject

Comment: @DominicvanEssen Those are from three separate test cases. I've updated the footer to make that clear.

Comment: 5 is disturbingly short. How many 5 byte Jelly programs are there?

Comment: @Simd Somewhere in the ballpark of a trillion, depending on how broken something can be to be considered a program :P

Answer (score 6):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `sets.extras`, <s>65 49</s> 47 bytes

```factor
[ [ last last ] sort-with [ first ] unique-by ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70sLTG5JL9owc0zocGefu5WCsWpJcV6qRUlRYnFCsX5RSWZeelAscLS1Lzk1GKF7NSivNQchYKi1JKSyoKizLwSBWuuai4FIKhWUPJJBCpXUlByVFKohYm5FQF1ZqAJ-iaWZBQDxZyQxOCatbAJYhFzwWZLKEiwdmlpSZquxU39aIVohZzE4hIIEQv2kG55ZkkGUDwtswgsVpqXCfSdblKlQixE27LkxJwcBT0IZ8ECCA0A)

- `[ last last ] sort-with` Sort the input by the last character of each grade.
- `[ first ] unique-by` Retain every entry that has a subject that has not been encountered before.

Comment: Factor looks very funny.

Answer (score 5):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 30 bytes

```
≔⦃⦄ηＦθＦ‹⮌§ι¹⮌∨§η§ι⁰Z§≔η§ι⁰§ι¹η
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjcXOBYXZ6bnaVTX6ihkaFpzpeUXKWgUaiqAaZ_U4mKNoNSy1KLiVA3HEs-8lNQKjUwdBUNNTR0FmLh_EVwqQ0cBSZUBSJVSlJImEChArMGlEIULNN2aK6AoM69EA-iiJcVJycVQ1y6PVtIty1GKvRkWHa2h5JNYkpmnBLTCUUsJaIKGkltRal5yBlgEIuCbWJJRDOI7YSjQQlPhrKQZGwuxBQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⦃⦄η
```

Start with no grades.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop over the input grades.

```
Ｆ‹⮌§ι¹⮌∨§η§ι⁰Z
```

If the reversed grade is less than the subject's reversed grade so far or `Z` if there is no grade yet, then...

```
§≔η§ι⁰§ι¹
```

... update the grade for that subject.

```
η
```

Output all of the grades in Python `dict` format.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> 7 (6?) [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

The second `Ô` could be removed if we could output the pairs in reverse order.

```
üÎËñÔÎÔ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/M7L8dTO1A&input=W1siTGF0aW4iLCJBIl0sWyJGcmVuY2giLCJBKiJdLFsiTWF0aHMiLCJCIl0sWyJMYXRpbiIsIkEqIl0sWyJNYXRocyIsIkMiXV0tUg)

```
üÎËñÔÎÔ     :Implicit input of 2D array
ü           :Group & sort by
 Î          :  First element
  Ë         :Map
   ñ        :  Sort by
    Ô       :    Reverse (mutating the arrays)
     Î      :  First element
            :  Reverse
```

---

### 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I *think* this works but it needs more testing.

```
üÎËñÍÎ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/M7L8c3O&input=W1siTGF0aW4iLCJBIl0sWyJGcmVuY2giLCJBKiJdLFsiTWF0aHMiLCJDIl0sWyJMYXRpbiIsIkEqIl0sWyJNYXRocyIsIkIiXV0tUg)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 42 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.sort().filter(v=>[v[0]!=x,x=v[0]][0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcvBCgIhEAbg@z6FedIw6S4u1MFTvcCKBzErQzRUxJ7e3IUOHYb5@eafl646m@Te5RDizXbBe@NzozmmgjC9O19sQpXPssqj2vFGGl@TGoM7mxaOGvngcR@LEMUmE0OO3lIfH0gguSB40cUFSAA8QUwAGCKSDea50f5nV102Oa/w9zUqCmPWvw)

Requiring an extra empty slot after each pair, which looks not that elegant

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 55 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.filter((v,i)=>!x.some(w=>v[0]>w[0]^[v,i--]>[w,0]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5BC8IgFAfw@z7F8vQMJ7sPhTrsVF9gYiDLyjCNTaZ9erPdgujyHvz@fx7vrhY1j5N5hsb5s849y4nxRC/GBj0BLMRgxjeJzv6hITK@iFbyWMZJlKxpJBeRtBLj3FUDg0RepS/Kkl01ejd7q6n1V@hBDIAOKhiHSI12CJO6/in9pN14W2n7z44qrLL/wNelUikPdfkN)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.map(v=>!v.l[1]&v.l>o[v.n]||[o[v.n]=v.l],o={})&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fcyxCoMwGATg3aewGSQpaaCz/IF2cGpfwJAhWGktMb@oBEF99jS1U6F0uuPjuKfxZqj6phsPDm91KCBMICfRmo56kDsvrDrqLIZE5YXTy6I@BaJpjjCvLMsw5EkJ1HHLQNI55srypEI3oK2FxTstqCopuZixcYSn5EQYT9OfUvS1qx4b7f/Z1YybnN/w9RQnmrE8vAA)

Comment: How many bytes needed to fix that? I mean get rid of the extra empty slot

Comment: @Simd Can't come up with a short solution to get rid of emptyslot

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 23 bytes

```
A\*
@$&
O`
D`.*,
G`,
@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fMUaLy0FFjcs/gcslQU9Lh8s9QYfLgev/f59EoAIdRy0ut6LUvOQMHUcu38SSjGIdJ7iAFlTEGQA) Takes input as a newline-separated list of subject, grade pairs. Explanation:

```
A\*
@$&
```

Prefix `@` to any `A*` grades.

```
O`
```

Sort everything into lexical order.

```
D`.*,
```

Delete duplicate subjects.

```
G`,
```

Remove lines whose subjects were deleted.

```
@
```

Remove any `@` prefixes.

Answer (score 4):

## awk, 53 bytes

51 bytes of AWK, in quotes, and 9 for shell invocation…

```shell
awk -F, '{if(t[$1]<$2)t[$1]=$2}END{for(s in t) print s,t[s]}'
```

As noticed by user [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen), there're cases that should be fixed that way (from 51 to 53):

```shell
awk -F, '$2$2<=t[$1]$2$2{t[$1]=$2}END{for(s in t)print s,t[s]}'
```

If use of blank delimiters (space or tab) is allowed,
we can shorten invocation with removal of `-F,`  (4 bytes)

### Usage and notes

…assuming that the table/list is represented by a pair `subject,grade` per line.
Then, you can echo the list directly

```shell
... | invocation
```

or put the list in a file

```shell
invocation < grades.txt
```

To [try](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_terminal_online.php), first create the `grade.txt` file this way

```
cat >grade.txt <<-EOF
  foo,A
  bar,A
  foo,A*
  baz,D
  fiz,E
  baz,B
EOF
```

or with `nano grade.txt` for example.

### Ungolfed/explanation

For golfing purposes I've used one letter variables and removed some extra spaces usually good for readability.

```
BEGIN {           # this block is processed once before main
IFS=","           # change Input Field Separator to comma...
}                 # ...or done via command option `-F ','`
{                 # this is the main block, executed for each line
  if (T[$1]<$2)   # build a Table indexed by first field (subject)
                  # when the second field (current grade) is greater
                  # than the existing value (cell initially empty) 
      T[$1]=$2    # then replace the table value with current grade
}
END {             # this block is executed once after main processing
  for(S in T)     # loop over the grades Table indexed by Subject
     print S,T[S] # for each entry, output the key (the Subject then)
                  # and the associated value (the maximum grade then)
}
```

I'm sure an AWK guru can improve it a little.

Comment: The 'highest grade' means that 'A' is higher than 'B': this code seems to incorrectly return 'B' when both 'A' and 'B' are present: [try it](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v@/OjNNoyRaxTDWRsVIE8ywVTGqdfVzqU7LL9IoVsjMUyjRVCgoyswrUSjWKYkujq39/19BIS0/X8eRC0I7QWlHrX/5BSWZ@XnF/3XddAA)

Comment: ...but can be [fixed](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fQ8VIxcjGtiRaxTAWxNSsBjNtVYxqXf1cqtPyizSKFTLzFEo0C4oy80oUinVKootja///V1BIy8/XceSC0E5Q2lELyEhKLAJLgGhnMF2l4wqlnWD0v/yCksz8vOL/um46AA) for +4 bytes...

Comment: (and by the way: no need to count the +9 for invocation.  Your score is the bytes of the AWK program itself.  To account for the ```-F,``` you should label the language as ```AWK -F,``` (see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/95126))).

Comment: [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxUjFyMa2JFrFMBbErAazbFWMal39XKrT8os0ihUy8xRKNAuKMvNKFIp1SqKLY2v//1dQSMvP13HkgtBOUNpRC8hISiwCS4BoZzBdpeMKpZ1g9L/8gpLM/Lzi/7puOgA)...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on how to count. I wanted to be fair, so the +9. Should I rename `awk` instead of `shell`? Also thanks for the fix, I've missed that case (to be frank, I didn't test with my example when I edited later, and checked only with the example in the question)

Comment: Also thanks for [TIO](https://tio.run/) I didn't know about. Your comments are precious for me @DominicvanEssen

Comment: Thanks @DLosc for spells and typos fix. Curation appreciated.

Comment: @gildux You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.¡н}εΣθR}н
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79DCC3trz209t/jcjqDaC3v//4@OVvJJLMnMU9JRclSK1YlWcitKzUvOAHG1wHzfxBIQzwnMgStFkXNWio0FAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
.¡ }        # Group the (implicit) input-list of pairs by:
  н         #  The first string of the pair (the subject)
    ε       # Then map over each group:
     Σ  }   #  Sort the list of pairs in this group by:
      θ     #   The last string of the pair (the grade)
       R    #   Reversed
         н  #  Then just keep the first pair
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 66 bytes

```perl
$f{$F[0]}.=$F[1]}{pairmap{say"$a ",(sort$b=~/./g)[0]=~s/\*/A*/r}%f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lrVrFLdogtlbPFkgbxtZWFyRmFuUmFlQXJ1YqqSQqKOloFOcXlagk2dbp6@mnawLV2tYV68do6Ttq6RfVqqb9/@@TWJKZp@DI5VaUmpecoeCoxeWbWJKh4MQFldD6l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQAEj7ZBaXWFmFlmTm2EIt/K@bmAcA)

Comment: 66 is long for perl!

Answer (score 3):

## Excel (ms365), 88 bytes

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(x,SORTBY(A1:B4,"*"&B1:B4,-1),y,TAKE(x,,1),FILTER(x,MATCH(y,y,0)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(x))))
```

Comment: Impressive! But I notice that B4 is hard-coded in the formula. Is there a way to write the formula so it still works if [up to 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/256441/remove-duplicates-from-my-academic-transcript?noredirect=1#comment567818_256441) subject/grade pairs are entered?

Comment: `=LET(x,FILTER(A:B,A:A<>""),y,SORTBY(x,"*"&DROP(x,,1),-1),z,TAKE(y,,1),FILTER(y,MATCH(z,z,0)=SEQUENCE(ROWS(x))))` would make the whole thing dynamic upto an insane amount of pairs if need be =).

Comment: A better way to handle the various array sizes is to assume that input is passed as a dynamic array of the form `={"Chemistry","A*";"Spanish","A"}` in cell `A1`. Then you can reference the whole array by using the Spilled Range Operator (`#`) by calling `A1#`

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 72 bytes

```bash
tr 'ABC*' '3210' | sort -k 2,2 -n -r | sort -k 1,1 -u | tr '3210' 'ABC*'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIQd3RyVlLXUHd2MjQQF2hRqE4v6hEQTdbwUjHSEE3T0G3CEnMUMdQQbcUKADSB9EA0f7/v09iSWaegqMWl1tRal5yhoIjl29iSYaCE5yvBRFw5gIA)

---

**Original Input**

```bash
Latin A*
French A
Math B
French A*
Math C
```

**`tr 'ABC*' '3210'`**

<sup>*Convert marks into numbers*</sup>

```bash
Latin 30
French 3
Math 2
French 30
Math 1
```

**`sort -k 2,2 -n -r`**

<sup>*Numeric sort using the 2nd field; reverse order*</sup>

```bash
French 30
French 3
Latin 30
Math 2
Math 1
```

**`sort -k 1,1 -u`**

<sup>*Sort using the 1st field only (already sorted); keep unique entries*</sup>

```bash
French 30
Latin 30
Math 2
```

**`tr '3210' 'ABC*'`**

<sup>*Reverse conversion*</sup>

```bash
French A*
Latin A*
Math B
```

Comment: I though of `sort` but didn't had the idea to convert grades to numbers with `tr` That's brillant. For golfing, short `sort -k 2,2 -n -r` to `sort -k2,2 -nr` (3 bytes less) and maybe `sort -nrk2,2` (5 bytes less). By the same `sort -k 1,1 -u` to `sort -k1,1 -u` (1 byte less) or even `sort -uk1,1` (3 bytes saved) ;)

Comment: I really love this!

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>183</s> <s>177</s> <s>164</s> 155 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat); -13 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil); -8 bytes thanks to [l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2)*

```c
#define F for(j=0;j<l;j++){for(i=0;strcmp(s[i],s[j]);i++);
i,j;f(s,g,l)char**s,**g;{F*g[i]>*g[j]|g[j][1]?g[i]=g[j]:0;}F i-j?:printf("%s %s\n",s[i],g[i]);}}
```

Defines a function `f` that takes an array of subjects, an array of grades, and an integer representing the length of both arrays. It prints each subject and the best grade in that subject to stdout. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVCxboMwEN35ihNVJOw4Ep0qxaVR2oZ2SDtlox6oY8BWMJHtTJRvpzZEkTp1ebp79@7e3fFVzfk43h1FJbWAHKrOJCpLqXo8UbVcoj4Q0hPWGd6eE1tIRmyhGKLSl2kkiaJVYklNTog3pcHYEoxr2ue49tonj4r9BCju2SZQWUjWKR1ykCu1WZ@N1K5K4oWFhf3SMZk8ghLRYbjttt99vh3e4SHyamhLqRMEfQQQTAHby7cS3NliljHIoI/3pZN@HsS5EZo3IfooXWP/pXa8010ruY0HerOoTXkUfw22OKi3AV6maMqfA7zO5NTv/3Ndj8A8hVzPQaFshLsYDSmNhvEX)

#### Ungolfed/explanation

This is <s>an awful mess</s> still pretty hacky, but looking a bit nicer than it originally did.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int i, j;
int f(char *subjects[], char *grades[], int length) {
  // Loop through the arrays using index j
  for(j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    // For each j, loop through the indices i before it until reaching one with the
    // same subject (i.e. the first entry for that subject)
    for(i = 0; strcmp(subjects[i], subjects[j]); i++);
    // Compare the grades by comparing their first characters (smaller characters
    // are better); if the first characters are the same, check if the second
    // grade has a second character (star is better than no star)
    // If the grade at index j is better than the grade at index i...
    if(grades[i][0] > grades[j][0] || grades[j][1]) {
      // Change the grade at index i to point to the grade at index j instead
      grades[i] = grades[j];
    }
  }
  // Loop through the arrays again
  for(j = 0; j < length; j++) {
    // Find the first entry for this subject
    for(i = 0; strcmp(subjects[i], subjects[j]); i++);
    // If the current entry is the first entry for this subject...
    if(i == j) {
      // Output the subject and the associated grade
      printf("%s %s\n", subjects[i], grades[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [164 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVCxTsMwEN3zFaegVo7rSGViMEEq0MBQmNhChuA6jq3GqWx3SvPtwXarSkwsp3vvnt@7M8sFY/N8t@et1BxKaAeDVLGm6vFA1WqVjYGQnrDOsP6IbCVrYitVZ1T6MU0kUbRFlghyyFjXGIwtwVjQscTCa/NQqvv6ySMVkApouUSBL0Q0mkqQuTqfj0Zq16J0YWFhv3VKYlgQes10W3K3/Xz7eoeHxKuhb6RGGYwJQEwHe/pRnDlbXWQ1FDCmu8ZJ7wdpabhmXeg@GtfZf6ktG/TQS2bTid4ihGn2/G/ABgf1JpSX2EX8HMrrhYzv/Udd1yNXF3I9Jwtjw93JaFjTZJp/AQ "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @Neil Ahh, of course--no need to copy the actual strings, just modify the pointers. Thanks!

Comment: `*g[i]-g[i][1]>*g[j]-g[j][1]` => `*g[i]>*g[j]|g[j][1]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 66 bytes

```arturo
$[a][select a'x[every? select a'y->x\0=y\0'z[>=last z\1last x\1]]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?yUwgOX)

```
$[a][                                ; a function taking an argument a
  select a'x[                        ; select pairs in a; assign current pair to x
    every?      <block>       'z[    ; is every element z in <block> true?
           select a'y->x\0=y\0       ; select pairs in a where subject = x's subject
      >=last z\1last x\1             ; is the last letter of z's grade >= x's?
    ]                                ; end every?
  ]                                  ; end select
]                                    ; end function
```